# Fuel Pump Failures

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-pump

I have a 2015 Hyundai Accent with 45,000kms. The tank fuel pump has failed twice and the high pressure fuel pump once. Anyone know what would cause such failures?

Comment: High pressure pumps usually fail due to lack of maintenance, the spring usually ends up breaking or the diaphragm starts to leak.

Comment: How certain are you that it's the fuel pump that's failing, have you checked for shorts, is the pump pumping fuel when power is applied to the 2 terminals that have continuity

Comment: That is one repair I had a mechanic perform. He said he only used OEM fuel pumps because after market and rebuilts were not as reliable and changing them out in the fuel tank was a job.

Answer (score 0):

Could well be poor ie cheap fuel - cheap fuel can be cheap because while it meets the minimum standards it can be light on some of the additives.

Another possibility is a cheap fuel filter but as it is relatively new perhaps not.